# Cheerio returns undefined when using the "contains" selector

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I am currently trying to parse some HTML from [this URL](https://www.rei.com/product/893905/rei-co-op-flash-60-pack-womens):

The main information I am after is the listed `Weight`. Using the Console in Chrome, I can issue the command:

```
$("th:contains(Weight)").parent()[0];
```

And it will give me the table rows containing all the information I need about the weight.

I tried to use this in Cheerio, but it just returns `undefined`. 
This is my Node.js code:

```
var needle = require('needle');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

function rei(product) {
    //Request page from rei.com and follow the redirect
    return needle("get", "https://rei.com/product/" + product, {
        follow_max: 5
    }).then(function(response) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

        var test = $("th:contains(Weight)").parent()[0];
        console.log(test);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
rei(893905);
```

What would be the best way to get the information I need from Rei's website in an automated manner?

Comment: Do view page source in chrome. The data is on the page but it's json so you'll have to parse it.

Comment: You should read data of response, (not html rendered in browser)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var needle = require('needle');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var fs = require('fs');

function rei(product) {
    //Request page from rei.com and follow the redirect
    return needle("get", "https://rei.com/product/" + product, {
        follow_max: 5
    }).then(function(response) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(response.body);

        // your data in script
        var content = $('script[data-client-store="product-details"]').html();

        content = JSON.parse(content);

        for (var spec of content.specs) {
            if (spec.name == 'Weight') {
                console.log(spec.values)
            }
        }

    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
rei(893905);
```